# Azure ARM Rest API for monitoring Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

I want to monitor Azure Storage Account but I'm not getting any documentation on ARM Rest API for getting the details like availability, metrics that can be collected etc.
In my resource group I have a storage account, so when I form the URL and do get using:

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/452529bb-083b-411a-a5c2-30c7352111d0/resourceGroups/SparkTraining/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sparktrainingdisks521?api-version=2017-06-01

I get the response.

But how to monitor blob, table, queue and file? also, what are the metric's that can be collected for these?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the [storage metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enabling-storage-metrics-and-viewing-metrics-data) from the following azure storage tables.
And we can get the table entity with Azure storage table [Query Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities) RestAPI. How to construct the authorization Header please refer to this [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services).

[image]

More info about these tables schema please refer to [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-metrics-table-schema).